# Trouble with JavaFX background threads

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I am having trouble getting this after hours of videos today.

Executer service, worker, task, concurrent package...?? I am confused as to what to do where.

I want to initialize several objects which post messages to the UI as they fire up.

I have an interface:

```
public interface SystemMessage {
    void postMessage(String outText);
}
```

One of my objects and some methods

```
public class Identity extends Service {
    private String machineId = null;

    private static SystemMessage systemMessage;

    public Identity(SystemMessage smInterface){
        systemMessage = smInterface;

        //how do i run the identity class in the background and report to the UI?
        // --------------------------------------------------
        //
        systemMessage.postMessage("Checking Machine Identity");
        if (getStoredIdentity()){
            systemMessage.postMessage("Machine ID exists.");
        }
        else{
            systemMessage.postMessage("No Machine ID. Create New.");
            machineId = createUuid();
            storeIdentity();
        }
    }
}

// --------------------------------------------------
//
//Do I create individual tasks for each method in the class? do i use service, task, executer, or????
// --------------------------------------------------
//

private void storeIdentity(){
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.setProperty("machineId", this.machineId);
    try {
        FileWriter file = new FileWriter("identity.properties");
        p.store(file, "Identity");
        systemMessage.postMessage("New Identity Created and Stored.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        systemMessage.postMessage("Error Creating New Identity!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My Main file that initializes several object on start.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("fxml/entry.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    mainController = (SystemMessage) loader.getController();
    primaryStage.setTitle("ASI Sync!");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
    primaryStage.show();
    initializeSync.start();
}

Thread initializeSync = new Thread (){
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Thread Running");
        Identity identity = new Identity(mainController);
        Api api = new Api(mainController);
        SqLite db = new SqLite(mainController);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the article to learn the actual details: [Concurrency in JavaFX | JavaFX 2 Tutorials and Documentation, JavaFX 2.1, Irina Fedortsova](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm).

Some important quotes from the article:

1. > ## Overview of the javafx.concurrent Package
   >
   > The Java platform provides a complete set of concurrency libraries available through the `java.util.concurrent` package. The `javafx.concurrent` package leverages the existing API by considering the JavaFX Application thread and other constraints faced by GUI developers.
   >
   > The `javafx.concurrent` package consists of the `Worker` interface and two basic classes, `Task` and `Service`, both of which implement the `Worker` interface. The `Worker` interface provides APIs that are useful for a background worker to communicate with the UI. The `Task` class is a fully observable implementation of the `java.util.concurrent.FutureTask` class. The `Task` class enables developers to implement asynchronous tasks in JavaFX applications. The `Service` class executes tasks.
   >
   > The `WorkerStateEvent` class specifies an event that occurs whenever the state of a `Worker` implementation changes. Both the `Task` and `Service` classes implement the `EventTarget` interface and thus support listening to the state events.
2. > The `Task` class defines a one-time object that cannot be reused. If you need a reusable `Worker` object, use the `Service` class.
3. > A task can be started in one of the following ways:
   >
   > - By starting a thread with the given task as a parameter:
   >
   >   ```
   >   Thread th = new Thread(task);
   >   th.setDaemon(true);
   >   th.start();
   >   ```
   > - By using the ExecutorService API:
   >
   >   ```
   >   ExecutorService.submit(task);
   >   ```

Hope this helps.